# Rxjs do not firing

Tags: rxjs

I know this is basic rx stuff, but I'm a little confused on when things decide to fire. Take the following:

```
Observable.of([1,2,3,4,5])
  .combineLatest([6,7,8,9,10])
  .take(1)
  .do(([first, second]) => console.log(first, second))
// ...Logs nothing...
```

Why doesn't that do anything until you subscribe to it? No logs are fired until I add a subscribe call to the end of the chain:

```
Observable.of([1,2,3,4,5])
  .combineLatest([6,7,8,9,10])
  .take(1)
  .do(([first, second]) => console.log(first, second))
  .subscribe(() => console.log('Subscribed'));
// Logs: 
// "5, 6" 
// "Subscribed"
```

Also, if I understand correctly, I don't need to unsubscribe since take(1) takes care of that for me, correct?

Comment: Best analogy for Rx is a pipeline. You have laid the pipe, and `subscribe()` opens the tap. Also, `take(1)` issues a complete notification after passing one item, which also unsubscribes the downstream subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example generates a *cold* observable - one which doesn't generate until you subscribe. The alternative is a *hot* observable which is generating regardless of observers and is shared between observers. see [hot and cold observables](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/Hot-and-Cold-Observables.aspx)

You can check whether your sequence is terminated by supplying the `onCompleted` callback (third parameter in subscribe). Like so:

```
rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5])
  .combineLatest(rx.Observable.from([6,7,8,9,10]))
  .take(1)
  .do(([first, second]) => console.log(first, second))
  .subscribe(() => console.log('Subscribed'), err=> { console.error(err)}, () => console.log('completed!!'));
```

Comment: Thanks! Hot/cold was helpful.